# SQL Server : querying to derive new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

I'm trying to create a Reneal table used for reporting table. I have a list of submissions that gets renewed each year and most often the policy number would be increased by 1.

For each Submission Number, I need to show the current policy number, its previous policy number and the next policy number.

For the first and last policy number of an account, the prior and next would be NULL.

My results using this query:

[image]

My desired outcome is as follows:

[image]

I'm tried this query and its providing incorrect results.. Any thoughts on how to proceed from here ?

```
with CurrentPolicy as 
(
    select 
        Region, 
        SubmissionNumber, 
        MasterPolicyNumber, 
        PolicyNumber, 
        NewRenewal, 
        Renewable,
        DateOfRenewal, 
        EffectiveDate, 
        ExpiryDate, 
        Coverage
    from 
        Policy_Dtl 
) 
select
    CurrentPolicy.SubmissionNumber, 
    left(PriorPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber, 14) + 
        right('00' + cast(right(PriorPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber, 2) - 1 as varchar(3)), 2) as Prior_MasterPolicyNumber,
    CurrentPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber, 
    left(NextPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber, 14) +
        right('00' + cast(right(NextPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber, 2) + 1 as varchar(3)), 2) as Next_MasterPolicyNumber,
    CurrentPolicy.PolicyNumber, 
    CurrentPolicy.NewRenewal, 
    CurrentPolicy.Renewable,
    CurrentPolicy.DateOfRenewal, 
    CurrentPolicy.EffectiveDate, 
    CurrentPolicy.ExpiryDate, 
    CurrentPolicy.Coverage
from 
    CurrentPolicy
left join  
    CurrentPolicy as PriorPolicy on CurrentPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber = PriorPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber
left join  
    CurrentPolicy as NextPolicy on CurrentPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber = NextPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber
where 
    CurrentPolicy.MasterPolicyNumber in ('42-XHF-150104-01', '42-PBL-150104-02', '42-EPF-150104-03', '42-EPF-150104-04','42-EPF-150104-05')
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "incorrect results"?  It would be helpful if you provided a small sample data set, along with the results you are getting and the results you expect to get.

Comment: No need for self-joins, have a look at LAG/LEAD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql, e.g. `LAG(MasterPolicyNumber) OVER (PARTTITON BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY EffectiveDate) AS PriorMasterPolicyNumber` (the PARTITION might be wrong)

Comment: Lag and Lead would output the results for a whole table right? I'm looking for previous and next value for each PolicyNumber

Comment: Doing it by group is the reason there is a PARTITION clause above.